# How do I vertically align the following flex element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flex setup:

```css
.col-12 {
  display: flex
}

input {
  flex: 0 0 80%
}

label {
  flex: 0 0 20%
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" value=""></input>
</div>
```

However, the label isn't aligned vertically:

[image]

I tried `vertical-aligment: middle` but `Message` stayed in the same place.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `align-items` property with the value `center`:

`align-items: center;`

Here's a link that I often refer to when I need a refresher and some examples when it comes to `flexbox`: [A Visual Guide to CSS3 Flexbox Properties](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).

```css
.col-12 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 36px;
  flex: 0 0 80%
}

label {
  flex: 0 0 20%
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

**PS** `<input>`s don't have a closing tag, they're [`void elements`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements). Sometimes referred to as *empty elements*.

Comment: Ah, you're right. And it's not necessary to write `<input/>` I think.

Comment: Correct you don't have to write `<input/>`, you can write `<input>` without the slash and be fine.

Comment: Oh, so i't's not possible to to align the element without height? Why did you set it to 36px?

Comment: I did that for demonstration purposes. Without it the input and text are almost the same height and would have been tough to see that the text was vertically aligning. Your screenshot clearly shows an `input` that has had some styling applied to it and is larger than an input styled with browser default styles.